# Pointcut expression that searches all methods in sub package pattern name?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have a spring context xml configuration with AOP point pointcut :

```
<aop:config>
  <aop:pointcut id="allOperation"
                expression="execution(* my.services.v2..*Test.*(..))"/>
  <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="allOperation"/>
</aop:config>
```

Which supposed to intercept any method in any sub package that ends with Test. 
Example of method supposed to be intercepted : my.services.v2.MyServiceTest.getSomeThink()

But it doesn't work, help me please

Comment: `MyServiceTest` is not a package, it's a class. You might also want to combine your `execution` expression with a `within` expression to simplify the pointcut syntax.

Comment: Can you give an example pleeese ? I've tried this 
expression="execution(* my.services.v2..*(..)) && within(*Test)"
But it doesn't work ((

Comment: I just figured out the problem is that I tray to intercept JUnit test's method which is not visible in Spring context

Comment: You could make your tests Spring `@Component`s and wire them into the application for testing. Or you can use AspectJ instead of Spring AOP, then it is also easy to get them intercepted. But why would you want to intercept tests instead of the things they actually do test?